# How do you import MigLayout into a Java Swing project?

Tags: java, jar, miglayout

I have a projet for my classes and I want to improve it a bit by using the external library [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com).

So I downloaded the jar file and imported it to my project's classpath.

I tried this to import the class but I don't think it's the right way to go :/ :

```java
package views;

import com.miglayout.MigLayout;  // <----

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class HomeView extends JFrame {

    ...

}
```

VS Code and Eclipse output: The package com is not accessible

Thanks in advance for your responses :)

Comment: `imported it to my project's classpath` If you did this correctly, it should work.  What is the actual error message?  What doesn't work?  Some info would be helpful.

Comment: @markspace VS Code and Eclipse output ```The package com is not accessible```

Comment: I would suggest editing the title of the question to make it mention MigLayout specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [API documentation](http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/mavensite/apidocs/net/miginfocom/swing/MigLayout.html), the correct class to import is:

```
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
```

Comment: Ordinarily, I would vote to close this question as a typo, but with this library, it took a bit of digging around to find the right package name. It’s missing from the quick start guide and cheat sheet. I think it will be useful to keep the question and answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Same.  I looked as well and couldn't find the relevant documentation.  The site the OP linked to could really use some attention by the developer(s).

Comment: @TimMoore thanks for your response but when I try to import it I got ```The package net.miginfocom.swing is not accessible```

Comment: Then I don’t know. Perhaps the JAR hasn’t been imported into the project correctly.

Comment: @TimMoore that's actually the first time I'm using library but I wasn't able to find an understandable tuto :/

Comment: Personally, I would recommend using a build tool such as Maven to manage library dependencies. There is an upfront learning curve, but it helps to establish a repeatable process. Most IDEs will integrate with it to import libraries automatically that are declared in your Maven configuration.